# Neural Net RNN algorithm for ML string match

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

I have raw data in csv as with column name w1 having company names.

```
w1
abcd  reit pvt ltd 
abcd reit  private ltd
ac abcd pte limited
abcd  reit pvt ltd
abcd singapore private limited company 
abcd  reit pvt ltd company 
abcd reit private limited company
abcd  reit private limited 
abcd  reit  private ltd
abcd   pte limited
abcd    reit pvt ltd company
abcd  singapore private limited company 
abcd  reit pvt ltd company 
abcd  reit private limited company
```

I am writing a neural net ML program which will learn by itself to identify similar company names. Only using ML algo like neuralnet, RNN etc

I created a column label to classify similar names belong to same group so my dataset becomes.

```
w1                                    label
abcd reit pvt ltd                        1
abcd reit  private ltd                   1
ac abcd pte limited                      2
abcd reit pvt ltd                        1
abcd singapore private limited company   3
abcd   reit pvt ltd company              1
abcd reit private limited company        1
abcd reit private limited                1
abcd  reit  private ltd                  1
abcd pte limited                         1
abcd reit pvt ltd company                1
abcd singapore private limited company   3
abcd reit pvt ltd company                1
abcd reit private limited company        1
```

I  created hash matrix but I am unable to feed this matrix to neural net.

Attached my code

```
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel("~/data.xlsx")
data1<-as.data.frame(data)
library(FeatureHashing)
library(Matrix)

###############  split data test train
library(caTools)
set.seed(101)
data2<-as.data.frame(data1)
# Create Split (any column is fine)
split = sample.split(data2$label, SplitRatio = 0.70)

# Split based off of split Boolean Vector
train = subset(data2, split == TRUE)
print(head(train,1))
test = subset(data2, split == FALSE)

hash.size(train)
d1<- hashed.model.matrix(label~  split(w1, delim= " "),
                      data = train, hash.size = 16, signed.hash = FALSE , 
create.mapping = TRUE)
```

Here I have problem as i dont know how to feed this d1 hash matrix into neuralnet
when I run input this hash matrix to neural net  I get error,

```
####### test hash input to neural net
nn <- neuralnet(
label~w1,
data=train, hidden=2, err.fct="sse",
linear.output=TRUE)

predicted.nn.values <- compute(nn,test[1:1] )
plot(nn)
```

Is there any other way to do this, Also I am not sure how to feed this d1 hash matrix into neural net

Comment: How big is the training dataset? And what is the input to the model? I assume it will a string representation of 2 companies and the output of the net would be the probability that they are the same?

Comment: Training data set contained 1000 records of company names , either in abbreviations like pvt ltd or in full , my  objective is to match the two company names with best probability

Comment: Yes you are right probability match ,, but using  only machine learning technique

Comment: 1000 records is too small to train a neural network in my opinion. It will just overfit. A deterministic method would achieve better results.

Answer (score 0):

I think an RNN is not the right tool here since company names are short sequences. A simpler model could be attempted first.

Paragraph vector (a generalized form of Word2vec) can be used to generate a high dimension representation of the company name.

Assuming paragraph vector gives a 300 dimension real valued vector, then the input to the model could be a pair company names (represented by a 300+300) dim vector. The output should be binary, where 1 indicates the same company and 0 indicates they are different.

Comment: dtMatrix <- create_matrix(data2)
    container <- create_container(dtMatrix, data2$label, trainSize=1:11, 
    virgin=FALSE)
    str(dtMatrix)
    # train a SVM Model
    model <- train_model(container, "SVM", kernel="linear", cost=1)
    model2 <- train_model(container, "NNET", kernel="linear", cost=1)
    predictionData <- list("htsg  reit pvt ltd", 
                       "htsg singapore private limited company", 
                       "HTSG pte limited", 
                       "htsg pte. systems", 
                       "ac HTSG pte limited ")

Comment: #predictionData <- list("dangerous be","donated many","generous mostly","TV");
library(tm)
library(RTextTools)
#trace("create_matrix",edit=T)
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(predictionData))
f<-TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
str(predictionData)
pd<-as.matrix(predictionData)
predMatrix <- create_matrix(predictionData, originalMatrix=dtMatrix)
predSize = length(predictionData) 
predictionContainer <- create_container(predMatrix, labels=rep(0,predSize), testSize=1:predSize , virgin=FALSE)
results <- classify_model(predictionContainer, model2)
results
plot(results)
#

Comment: Please describe your approach in plain English, I am not familiar with R.

Comment: Actually I'm converting text to vector numeric  first and then feed to svm or nnet  , training set and then predict.

Answer (score 0):

Did your approach work?

Another way would be.

- clean all then names from weird characters etc.
- Create a train dataset on comparing two company names and give one or zero if they match. Fuzzy matching (leveinstein distance) would help on that, in the sense that you could run it to give you the most possible options and then manually assign them. (this would require some time) 
  or maybe find another ready train dataset.
- Then use the bag of words aka embedding to transform the string to a numerical vector.
  and then apply some NN. I do not think that RNN would be the best options, but I am not sure about that